# Вывести из колонки БД, в которой хранится xml, данные из определённого тэга

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Есть xml такого вида

```
 <Extension>
  <Item Key="TIME" Value="15.08.19 18:00:16" />
  <Item Key="FACCT" Value="1234567891234567893" />
  <Item Key="LTIME" Value="15.08.19 18:00:16" />
  <Item Key="AVLBAL" Value="31354" />
</Extension>
```

Он хранится в поле **atribut** в таблице **table**. Как вытащить значение из **"value"** из ключа **"FACCT"**?

Способ обрезать  **substring** по количеству знаков не подходит, так как ключ **"FACCT"** может находиться в другой строке.

Comment: по хорошему надо xml парсить, но можно и "на коленках" с помощью регулярок
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311360/sql-server-string-extract-based-on-pattern

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev SQ: Server поддерживает тип данных XML и позволяет к нему запросы писать.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @x  XML = CAST ('
<Extension>
  <Item Key="TIME" Value="15.08.19 18:00:16" />
  <Item Key="FACCT" Value="1234567891234567893" />
  <Item Key="LTIME" Value="15.08.19 18:00:16" />
  <Item Key="AVLBAL" Value="31354" />
</Extension>'
AS XML);

DECLARE @Key AS NVARCHAR(128) = 'FACCT';

SELECT n.val.value('(@Value)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
FROM (
    SELECT @x xmlCol
) x
CROSS APPLY x.xmlCol.nodes('.//Item[@Key=sql:variable("@Key")]') n(val)
```

**UPD:**

Для таблицы вместо

```
FROM (
        SELECT @x xmlCol
    ) x
```

используйте

```
FROM YourTableName x
```

И замените xmlCol на имя своего XML-столбца.

Comment: Денис, спасибо за ответ. но не совсем понятно где здесь имя поля в котором хранятся данные в xml формате и таблица где хранятся эти данные

Comment: Спасибо! все работает.